# Mysql marge 5 columns into one and repleace row

Tags: mysql, str-replace

So i have question:

```
SELECT worker_ID as widp, DAYS, MAX(ID_WERSJI) max , funcion1 as FUN1,function2 as FUN2,function3 as FUN3,function4 as FUN4,function5 as FUN5
                FROM `grafik201105`
                    WHERE 
                        funcion1 IN ('one','two','three','four','five','six') OR
                        function2 IN ('one','two','three','four','five','six') OR
                        function3 IN ('one','two','three','four','five','six') OR
                        function4 IN ('one','two','three','four','five','six') OR
                        function5 IN ('one','two','three','four','five','six') AND
                        active=1 
                        GROUP BY widp, FUN1,DAYS) as dni
```

And now i need to get fun1,fun2,fun3,fun4 and fun5 in one column ('give_me_all')
AND! in fun1='one' replace 'one' to 'first', if 'two' then second, three => third...

i try to use if(fun1='one','first',fun1) but I think that better solution here is to use CASE but i don't know exactly how to use it

Comment: be careful using OR and AND in one place without using brackets. It will firstly execute `(function5 IN ('one','two','three','four','five','six') AND
                        active=1 )` and only then the other OR's so I assume it is not what you wanted to do.

Comment: If you want to use `CASE` which seems logical, you should write a function to translate one into first and so on.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius, brackets? could you please show me some example? I don't know what it is. Aaah, and what about to marge those five columns?

Comment: Yes. `( funcion1 IN ('one','two','three','four','five','six') OR
                        function2 IN ('one','two','three','four','five','six') OR
                        function3 IN ('one','two','three','four','five','six') OR
                        function4 IN ('one','two','three','four','five','six') OR
                        function5 IN ('one','two','three','four','five','six') ) AND
                        active=1 `

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius, I did not know about it, thanks. Although in my query is not much change, but good to know for the future.
And what about the rest of my problem? How to combine this five columns combined into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to combine two or more columns into one you just simply do `(function1+function2+function3+function4+function5) AS give_me_all`, but as I said, the best should would be to make a function for you to replace `one` to `first` and it would then go like `(change(function1)+change(function2)+change(function3)+change(function4)+change(function5)) AS give_me_all`, but writing a function is a more advanced thing. Try reading more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html).
Otherwise it will look ugly, but still possible

```
`((CASE 
     function1 
        WHEN 'one' THEN 'first';
        WHEN 'two' THEN 'second';
  END;)+
  (CASE 
     function2 
        WHEN 'one' THEN 'first';
        WHEN 'two' THEN 'second';
  END;)
  ...) AS give_me_all`
```

See how bad it looks? Better learn to write your own function :)